# Как изменить надпись к полю с загрузкой файлов, выводимую через Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: javascript, css, razor

На сайте загрузка файла реализована так:

```
<div class="common-row">
    <label class="common-label">
        @Resources.Documents
    </label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Files, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple", @class = "input-file" })
    <div class="error__input">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Files, "", new { @class = "text-validation-error" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Но, это выводится в таком виде. Меня смущает надпись **Выбрать файл** и **Файл не выбран**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу убрать надпис **Файл не выбран**, а **Выбрать файл** заменить на **Обзор**. Пошерстил интернет, нашел способы сделать это через CSS. Но, все это для случаев, когда поле объявлено через

```
<input type='file'>
```

и в CSS описывается стили отдельно для кнопки, отдельно для текста и тд.

Подскажите, как можно изменить надписи для моего случая средствами Razor?

Comment: Текст браузер сам подставляет, причем в разных браузерах он может быть разный. Изменять его нельзя. Только прятать сам инпут.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `Razor` никак. Только с помощью `css` прятать сам инпут и файл выбирать по `label` к инпуту:

```css
.common-row input[type="file"] {
  display:none;
}
.common-row input[type="file"] + label {
  display:block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline
}
```

```html
<div class="common-row">
    <input type="file" id="file">
    <label class="common-label" for="file">
        Выбрать файл
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: То есть мне надо убирать реализацию через хелпер Html.TextBoxFor и делать по другому :/

Comment: Нет, не надо, Razor только генерирует html, который вы можете потом подогнать в css. в моем примере примерно тот-же самый html, который у вас на выходе, надо только добавить for для label и id для инпута